# Testing Action Creator with Redux Thunk & Axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, chai, redux-thunk

I've got a redux-thunk action creator that makes an API request via axios, the outcome of that request then determines what sort of action is dispatched to my reducer (AUTH or UNAUTH).

This works quite well but I am unsure of what the proper way is to test this functionality. I've arrived at the solution below but have the following error in my test:

```
1) AUTH ACTION
   returns a token on success:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Now this error leads me to believe that what i'm really getting back from my action creator isn't a promise but i'm really struggling to find a way forward.

**src/actions/index.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

import { AUTH_USER } from "./types";

const ROOT_URL = "http://localhost:";
const PORT = "3030";

export function signinUser({ email, password }) {
  return ((dispatch) => {
    axios
      .post(`${ROOT_URL}${PORT}/signin`, { email, password })
      .then(response => {
        // update state to be auth'd
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
        // Save token locally
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: AUTH_ERROR, payload: error });
      });
  });
}
```

**test/actions/index_test.js**

```
import { expect } from "../test_helper";
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import moxios from 'moxios';

import { AUTH_USER } from "../../src/actions/types";

import { signinUser } from "../../src/actions/index";

const middleware = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middleware);
let store;
let url;

describe('AUTH ACTION', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    moxios.install();
    store = mockStore({});
    url = "http://localhost:3030";
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    moxios.uninstall();
  });

  it('returns a token on success', (done) => {
    moxios.stubRequest(url, {
      status: 200,
      response: {
        data: {
          token: 'sample_token'
        }
      },
    });

    const expectedAction = { type: AUTH_USER }

    let testData = { email: "test1@test.com", password: "1234"}
    store.dispatch(signinUser(testData)).then(() => {
      const actualAction = store.getActions()
      expect(actualAction).to.eql(expectedAction)
    })
  })
})
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`store.dispatch(someThunk()).then()` only works if the thunk returns a promise, and your thunk isn't actually returning a promise.

If you just put a `return` in front of `axios()`, it *should* work.

Comment: Thank you so much!